# Loading a cross-domain iframe in a private browser logs user out

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I'm working with a client where I am making a small dedicated one off site on a sub domain. They want me to use their API to make a simple post request when a user hits a button, but the client does not want the user to log in again, instead wants them to use the access token from the main site. So I asked their engineers to add a response to a postMessage from my subdomain with the access token

The domain structure will be like this:

Site1 - https://www.example.com

Site2 - https://sub.example.com

and a very simple example of what I have and what they have:

```
//set the src of the iframe
$("#main-site-iframe").attr("src", "https://www.example.com");
//wait for the main site page to open
$("#main-site-iframe")[0].onload = () => {
    //my page posts a message to their site
    $("#my-iframe")[0].contentWindow.postMessage("jwt", "https://www.example.com");  
};
```

```js
//their site listens for a request
window.addEventListener('message', tokenRequest, false);
function tokenRequest(e) {
    //make sure the request is from the correct subdomain
    if(e.origin == 'https://sub.example.com')
    {
        //respond with the access token
        e.source.postMessage(authJWT, e.origin);
    }
}
```

Normally the steps go like this:

- Login to Site1
- Press a button that loads Site2
- Site2 loads an iframe that has Site1 in it
- Since the user is already logged into Site1, they are already logged into the site inside the iframe
- Site2 does a postMessage to get the jwt
- Site1 responds with the jwt
- Everything worked correctly we now have the jwt so we can use the API

Under normal circumstances this all works correctly, but this does not work in private browsers for some reason.

- Login to Site1
- Press a button that loads Site2
- Site2 loads an iframe that has Site1 in it
- Loaded Site1 does NOT have the user logged in
- Site2 does a postMessage and gets a response of false because they are not logged in
- I Redirect to Site1's Login Screen, because I assume they're actually logged out

Somehow the loading of the iframe causes the user to be completely logged out(going to the home page in another tab shows the user is actually logged out)

The weirdness is that this only happens the first time in a private window, and if the user repeats the first few steps again, the second time the page works correctly(unless they close the private browser and start over) So if you follow this, it works correctly

- Login to Site1
- Press a button that loads Site2
- Site2 loads an iframe that has Site1 in it
- Loaded Site1 does NOT have the user logged in
- Site2 does a postMessage and gets a response of false because they are not logged in
- I Redirect to Site1's Login Screen, because I assume they're actually logged out
- Login to Site1 AGAIN
- Press a button that loads Site2
- Site2 loads an iframe that has Site1 in it
- Since the user is already logged into Site1, they are already logged into the site inside the iframe
- Site2 does a postMessage to get the jwt
- Site1 responds with the jwt
- Everything worked correctly

Is there something I'm missing with the postMessage that I don't know about or something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the behaviour was caused by some back and forth with http vs https. The dev servers don't have a ssl cert so it was never an issue(it always used http), and the staging server does but it's not enforced(so it can switch between http and https) This actually would have worked on production since production enforces https it just failed on staging because https is not enforced.

Since the browser treats http and https as separate pages, the session token was not in local storage on the other depending on what page was logged into first. It went something like this:

```
Login to Site1 on https
Press a button that loads Site2 on http
Site2 loads an iframe that has Site1 but in http
Loads Site1 in http does NOT have the user logged in
Site2 does a postMessage and gets a response of false because they are not logged in
Redirect to Site1's Login Screen but this time on http
User logs in again on http not https
Press a button that loads Site2 on http
Loads Site1 in http and DOES have the user logged in this time
Everything works
```